# Calculate reverse polynomial for given polynomial for calculating CRC

Tags: javascript, crc

I am writing a javascript code for calculating the reverse polynomial from given generator polynomial but there seems to be some error it works great for few CRC method (CRC-8, CRC-16, CRC-CCITT, CRC-32, CRC-32C) but not for all of them .. please point out where i am going wrong.

```
<input type="text" name="poly" id="poly" onkeyup="getRevPoly()">
<input type="text" name="rpoly" id="rpoly" disabled>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getRevPoly() {
  var poly = document.getElementById('poly').value;
  var bin = convertBase(poly, 16, 2);
  bin = pad(bin, (poly.length));
  bin = bin.split('').reverse().join('');
  var hex2 = convertBase(bin, 2, 16);
  document.getElementById('rpoly').value = hex2.toUpperCase();
}
function convertBase(num, baseA, baseB) {
          return parseInt(num, baseA).toString(baseB);
}

function pad(num, size) {
      var s = num;
      while (s.length < (size * 4)) s = "0" + s;
      return s;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because a lot of people may not know what these terms are, it would be helpful for you to link to the algorithm(s) that you are trying to implement. In addition, it would be good to know what error you're getting, what you're expecting from the output, and what you're getting instead.

Comment: there aint any CRC algorithm used here ...its just simple convertion of generator polynomial to reverse polynomial ... like for CRC-8-CCITT the polynomials hex value is **07** when entered should give output **E0**

Comment: @MarkAdler : but doesn't give correct answer for **CRC-5-EPC** , **CRC-5-ITU** , **CRC-5-USB** , etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code will only work for CRCs with lengths that are a multiple of four bits.  So it won't work for the CRC-5s you (finally) mention in the comments to your question.  In fact, there is no code that can take a hexadecimal representation of a polynomial sans the high term and magically deduce the number of bits.  You need another input which is the number of bits in the CRC.